# Build input file cannot be found for generated Coredata class and extension when open project on different computer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, xcode9

I am new to Core Data and my first project I build using it work perfectly on my main computer. However, when I push the code to git repo, my other team mate encounter problem. More specifically the generated Coredata class and extension for my one and only core data model cannot be found. 
When I generate the core data files: I save it in Model folder in the main app project like so:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl5N5.png)

The image is the project open on another computer showing that Xcode cannot find the file even though they are exist in the folder.
The error I encounter on the same computer :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FALM.png)

From examining the error, I realised that Xcode is using the absolute path for these 2 file which only work on my main computer which I used to develop the project. 
However, I have no idea how to fix it. Does anyone has any idea what is going on.

Here is the coredata model settings I used when generate the class and extension file by doing Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXYky.png)

I am using Xcode 9.4.1 version for development and my other computer I used that ran into error is using Xcode 10. However I don't think it is a compatible issue since my other team mates are using Xcode 9.4.1. And they ran into the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution for the problem right after posting this question :). When the 2 file is generates, Xcode make the location settings to be "Absolute path" for some reason. So I changed it to "Relative to group"